# Launch DOSBOX to run exe but also mount the ultradir directory

Tags: audio, dosbox

I want to create a launcher for DOSBOX that directly starts DOOM. I do this by using the following (I'm on Linux):

```
dosbox ~/games/DOOM/DOOM.EXE
```

This works great, however, I want to use Gravis UltraSound emulation for sound, not Sound Blaster. To enable UltraSound, DOSBOX needs access to the UltraSound drivers and the DOSBOX config requires the directory for these drivers to be set with the `ultradir` setting.

How can I launch DOOM and also make the `ultradir` directory available to DOSBOX?

Comment: you can edit the config file and configure it in there. You can even launch doom from the config file.

Comment: I know how, but when I start DOOM with the [name] parameter to an executable, it mounts that directory the EXE is in as C:\. So, given that, how do I make DOSBOX aware of the ULTRASOUND directory? [without copying the ULTRASND directory into my game directory of course]

Comment: I don't know it from the back of my head, but the documentation on the dosbox site is good enough to figure it out from there. I do not have time to research it right now, because I can't test it.